# Rewrite Rule Help ! First Time?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help, It´s my first time using the Rewrite Rule for a link.

My website is a eshop.

The url will be something like this:

www.mydomain.com/shop.php

This file, shop.php will receive up to 3 parameters throught the url.

Example:

Case 1: www.mydomain.com/shop.php?page=1

Case 2: www.mydomain.com/shop.php?page=1&category=1

Case 3: www.mydomain.com/shop.php?page=1&category=1&subcategory=3

What I need is that the Rewrite Rule returns me something like:

Case 1: www.mydomain.com/shop.html/1

Case 2: www.mydomain.com/shop.html/1/FeaturesItems/

Case 3: www.mydomain.com/shop.html/1/FeaturesItems/BrandName

Let's Imagine that FeaturesItems is the Category that his Id is the number 1.

Let's Imagine that BrandName is the SubCategory that his Id is the number 3.

Can you help me to create the rewrite rule?

The other question is, in shop.php I can read the $_GET['category'] with the Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to acomplish a call to `/shop/15` and redirect this internaly to `shop.php?category=15`. Then do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shop.html/(\d+)$ shop.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shop.html/(\d+)/FeaturedItems/ shop.php?category=$1&featured=1 [L]
```

and so on.

(untested)

Maybe get a more indepth look of how mod_rewrite works. For example:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

I could also recommend the excelent [mod_rewrite-Cheat-Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/). Also check the tutorial section there.

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for your answer. I tried to do the first RewriteRule and it seems to work, but the page loads without the css Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The `RewriteRule` will catch every request that the server has to handle. Also, the browser will request the css file based on the URL it sees. For example, if you have something like `/shop/feature/` as the current location and reference to the CSS file is `css/style.css` the browser will try to look for `/shop/feature/css/style.css`. Check the network tab of your developer console to see which URL the browser requests.