# static page redirect with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page which name is pageid5.asp but in url i want to access it by page.asp?ID=5.

I try to handle it by .htaccess file but not success. My code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule page.asp?ID=5 pageid5.asp
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a query string in the `test string` of RewriteRule.
It needs to be handled this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(.+)
RewriteRule ^page.asp$ pageid%1.asp [L]
```

**Let me know how this works out.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, you make my day. I want to know, can i add more rewriteCond??

Comment: What kind of conditions?

Comment: Can you pls tell me how i can handle more than one parameter like
page.asp?ID=5&services=public pageid5servicespublic.asp

Comment: You can add this rule. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(.+)&services=(.+)` `RewriteRule ^page.asp$ pageid%1services%2.asp [L]`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see why you need a `RewriteCond` here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525892/rewrite-rule-help-first-time/33526117

Comment: @PatrikMayer you need one because he's trying to match on the query string. Meaning the URL in the browser has a query string attached. That's what he asked for. And you can't use a query string in the test string of the rewriterule hence the condition. Read the section here called [What is matched?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)